# Is there a way to make a leaflet popup responsive using react-leaflet library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, popup, react-leaflet

I've been researching and I know [leafletjs](https://leafletjs.com/) has the plugin https://github.com/yafred/leaflet-responsive-popup but I need a workaround for the library I'm using [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet).

The [react-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet) has a lot of third-party plugins but I don't see anything that works for me.
If someone knows how or has done something like this it would be cool if you could share it. I'm having a hard time with this.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to integrate `leaflet-responsive-popup` on react using also react-leaflet. Correct?

Comment: Yup! That's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the library, import js, css get a map reference and then render the marker:

```
import R from "leaflet-responsive-popup";
import "leaflet-responsive-popup/leaflet.responsive.popup.css";
...
  const position = [51.505, -0.09];
  const mapRef = useRef();

  const icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
    shadowUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.0/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    const marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], { icon });
    const popup = R.responsivePopup({
      hasTip: true,
      autoPan: true,
      offset: [15, 20]
    }).setContent("A pretty CSS3 responsive popup.<br> Easily customizable.");

    marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(popup);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Map center={position} ref={mapRef} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
    </Map>
  );
```

**Edit**
To have the plugin independent in an external wrapper component you can have a ResponsivePopup wrapper file:

```
const ResponsivePopup = () => {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();
  console.log(map);

  useEffect(() => {
    const marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], { icon });
    const popup = R.responsivePopup({
      hasTip: true,
      autoPan: true,
      offset: [15, 20]
    }).setContent("A pretty CSS3 responsive popup.<br> Easily customizable.");

    marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(popup);
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

in which this time you will get the map reference using the useLeaflet hook provided by react-leaflet library and then you act similarly with the first solution.
This time your Map or App comp will become like this:

```
 <Map center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      // here use your custom wrapper for responsive popup
      <ResponsivePopup />
    </Map>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-leaflet-responsive-popup-library-in-react-leaflet-w0909)

Comment: Great, this works but I was wondering if there's a way for leaflet-responsive-popup to be defined as a react element instead of using javascript.  Like <ResponsivePopup></ResponsivePopup> instead of <Popup></Popup>