# implement leaflet-responsive-popup plugin with react leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

It is more theoretical question, rather than some problem. I am kind of a newbie to adding maps to my app. I have found that using react leaflet is somewhat manageable . however lately I stumbled upon a plugin for the original leaflet `leaflet-responsive-popup` that will allow me to change the display of popups. however I am strugling on how to implemente it with react leaflet.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925036/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-leaflet-popup-responsive-using-react-leaflet-library/60938279#60938279)

Comment: @kboul thank you I upvoted your answer

Comment: @kboul I did implement your suggestion but I faced a new challenge. if you can please help me with this issue , I created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873505/react-leaflet-updating-markers)