# react leaflet updating markers

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

hello I am a leaflet newbie, I am building my app with map component. the marker on the map should be updated every time the user perform specific action (filters) . the component was working fine . then I decided to add the responsive popup plugin from the original Leaflet. so I tweaked a lot the normal component of react leaflet . now every time I perform I new filters the new markers are added successfully to the map however the  old marker are not deleted.

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-https-uw7gy)

any help on how to fix this ?

Comment: Could you create a small demo to reproduce this?

Comment: @kboul I edited my question and added a sandbox link to a demo

Comment: @Youssef, I sent you two solutions, one is with and one without ResponsivePopup. To be honest I would go without ResponsivePopup (one less dependency and more declarative syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not bound to that component (leaflet-responsive-popup) you can solve it like this (preferred solution):
[CodeSandbox without ResponsivePopup](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-haibt-sbkcb)

```
<Marker key={i} position={bus}>
  <Popup>
    <span>Note<br />{i}</span>
  </Popup>
</Marker>
```

If you have to use that component than you have to store markers in an array and clear all the markers before you add new ones like this:
[CodeSandbox with ResponsivePopup](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-silence-gn1hl)
Problem is that you were adding markers, while never removing the old ones. You have to pass all the coordinates so that first you could remove the old ones and than add the new ones.

Comment: thanks a lot. so even with the nice feature that this plugin have .  on your point of view it is better not to include the responsive popup plugin ?  because it is true I did find some issue integrating it with react leaflet, and the react environment in general. so do you have any sugestion on how to make popup style responsive without a plugin? I really apreciated your help

Comment: I don't know how much freedom do you have with the placement of the popup. If it can be in a fixed position (e.g. edge of the map) you could consider using React elements. If your app is map heavy and you are not bound to React than you might consider using Leaflet directly (it should be more performant).